# Não consigo alterar um atributo da minha matriz

Tags: java

@EDIT Apresentando um exemplo mínimo, conforme solicitado:

MAIN

```
    package teste;
public class TESTE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tabuleiro cenario = new Tabuleiro(1);
        cenario.setVisibilidade();
    }

}
```

CLASSE ABSTRATA PEÇA

```
public abstract class Peça extends JFrame{
    ImageIcon normal;
    boolean VISIVEL;

    Peça(ImageIcon normal){
        this.normal = normal;
    }
    private String TIPO;
    public String getTipo(){
        return this.TIPO;
    }
    public void setTipo(String tipo){
        this.TIPO = tipo;
    }
}
```

CLASSE TABULEIRO

```
public class Tabuleiro extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private int cont;
    private int DIFICULDADE,PLIN,PCOL; // PLIN = POSIÇÃO LINHA, PCOL = POSIÇÃO COLUNA
    private Peça tabuleiro[][];
    public Tabuleiro(int op){ // UM DOS POSSÍVEIS CONSTRUTORES
        super("Zumbicídio");
        this.cont = 0;
        this.DIFICULDADE = op;
        this.tabuleiro = new Peça[10][10];

    }
    public void setVisibilidade(){
        int i, j,plin,pcol;
        //DEIXANDO TODO O TABULEIRO INVISÍVEL
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(j=0;j<10;j++){
               this.tabuleiro[i][j].VISIVEL = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Basicamente, minha "matriz de Peça" (tabuleiro[10][10]) possui um atributo boolean "VISIVEL" (mostrado na primeira classe). Eu desejo setar esse atributo como FALSE em todo o tabuleiro, a princípio. Porém, eu fazer isso, recebo o erro

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

na linha

```
this.tabuleiro[i][j].VISIVEL = false;
```

do método acima.

Esse código é suficiente para identificar o erro?

obs: destaquei as variáveis usando asteriscos.

Comment: Apresente um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executar o codigo. Acesse o link para aprender a fazer um.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu array é multidimensional que comporta apenas tipos `Peças`(que já é um erro utilizar acentos em nomes de variáveis), mas ao iniciar o array desta forma:

```
this.tabuleiro = new Peça[10][10];
```

você está apenas alocando espaço na memória para que esse array possa receber quantidade n de peças dentro desse array apenas. Nenhuma peça foi criada dentro dele, apenas espaços nulos.

Você precisa, além de iniciar o array, também alocar ele com objetos do tipo `Peça`, instanciando um por posição, senão será apenas um array cheio de espaços nulos.